# Who/What is AS4100000000?

Tags: routing, route-filter

I have seen AS4100000000 in some routing datasets I am working with, for example Routeviews:

```
194.153.134.0/24 AS4100000000
```

I would like to understand where it is coming from or who controls it so I know how to deal with it, i.e. if I can safely ignore it. My research so far didn't reveal helpful results.

Here is an example of what I did find, there was an announcement but no AS information seems to be available: https://www.cidr-report.org/cgi-bin/as-report?as=4100000000&view=6447 another https://bgp.he.net/AS4100000000

It is not in the bogon/internal use number ranges, so it should be valid but it still seems to be outside of normal use.

I guess the simplest explanation is that this is simply a leak? If that is the case, is there any significance to this number, i.e. why wasn't a number reserved for internal use chosen instead?

Answer (score 3):

BGPView [1] has it listed as an Austrian company EDV Consulting Zoichter GmbH, but this may also be a glitch in the reporting output owing to it not having a registry entry and reprinting the prior entry.

HE shows that it is originating only a single prefix 194.153.134.0/24 [2], which looks to be owned by a Polish systems integrator call Atman [3][4]

I suspect that you are right and this is just a leak, by Atman (their real public AS is 24748)[5] and 4100000000 is listed as a peer.

- [1] https://bgpview.io/asn/57463#peers-v4
- [2] https://bgp.he.net/AS4100000000#_prefixes
- [3] https://www.whois.com/whois/194.153.134.0
- [4] http://atman.pl
- [5] https://bgp.he.net/AS24748#_peers